# php listing a directory files by first the newest

Tags: php, linux, file, list, filesystems

Here is the thing I am trying to create a CMS blog based in files.

And to display the posts i need te get the 10 latest files in a folder.

I found [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), but i do not what it to have to read all the files, and then sort them because, then the time it take to process dependes on the number of files.

So i found [opendir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php), this way i could go through the folder file by file but, as the documentation of opendir tells, it uses the order of the file system wich in linux is based on timestamp but first comes the latest file modified.

So what i ask is there a way to change how linux orders the files in a folder.
Or is there a way to do what i want?

Comment: Where does the documentation say opendir outputs in date order?  I'm pretty sure it's in arbitrary order (maybe ascending inode order).

Comment: @therefromhere [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) first comment

Comment: I believe you have to read all the files (use scandir) because you are essentially sorting an unordered list which at best is O(n*log(n))... and linux doesn't appear to allow you to change order of files. Out of curiosity why are your posts files and not MySql entries?

Comment: @Tomas I'm pretty sure from experience that that's wrong (or at least filesystem dependent).  You might well get them in order at first though...

Comment: @therefromhere, you're probably right I don't have much experience with file management and php; just thought I'd share my $0.02.

Comment: @Tomas yeah no worries - I added a note to that page to indicate the previous comment is wrong.  If only it was a stackoverflow page ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php, in user comments it has an example to get the newest file for instance, which you could modify to return 10 latest files based on their mtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a folder with lots of file, and worry about the performance of the scandir,
you can consider to setup a cronjob to do background scandir + sorting,
make sure you store the result into another storage like memcache /database / disk-file

Let's said you cronjob is running every 5 minute,
your cronjob script should overwrite the results on the storage
only upon success (after end of the scandir + sorting)

So, your CMS script is just to read from the storage,
or if results from storage is not found,
then proceed with the scandir + sorting

Usually the first user hit the page and the cache is not ready, he will get a very slow response,
that's the reason to use a cronjob is to do the pre-cache

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help you, but the code I have will list all files instead of only the last 20, easy to add that and tis code will list newest to oldest:

```
<?PHP

$directory="photos";
$sortOrder="newestFirst";

   $results = array();
   $handler = opendir($directory);

while ($file = readdir($handler)) { 
       if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != "robots.txt" && $file != ".htaccess"){
           $currentModified = filectime($directory."/".$file);
           $file_names[] = $file;
           $file_dates[] = $currentModified;
       }   
   }
       closedir($handler);

   //Sort the date array by preferred order
   if ($sortOrder == "newestFirst"){
       arsort($file_dates);
   }else{
       asort($file_dates);
   }

   //Match file_names array to file_dates array
   $file_names_Array = array_keys($file_dates);
   foreach ($file_names_Array as $idx => $name) $name=$file_names[$name];
   $file_dates = array_merge($file_dates);

   $i = 0;

   //Loop through dates array and then echo the list
   foreach ($file_dates as $$file_dates){
       $date = $file_dates;
       $j = $file_names_Array[$i];
       $file = $file_names[$j];
       $i++;

       echo  "<img src=photos/$file>\n";       
   }

?>
```

Hope that helps you.

cheers